# ajaxupload, can't seem to find a succinct tutorial

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous, asyncfileupload

I am trying to asynchronously upload pictures to my webserver.  There are a couple of good tutorials on the web, but they seem to be dated already...
Namely:
http://css-tricks.com/6522-ajax-image-uploading/
http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/

In both tutorials they ask you to include ajaxupload.js into your header file.  And both seem to be referenceing a tutorial by some dude named valums.  Well, when I download his code, that jquery (or javascript) library doesn't seem to be found anywhere.  Am I missing something here?  To get this thing to work, what javascript library should I be including?

Comment: Looks like I got a couple of demerits here.  Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are using jquery. in the download script they must be using from google's api. that is why you can't the jquery file. look in the html file and you will know where the jquery file is. simple!

Comment: Huh? Don't quite understand what you mean here.